# How to include my helpers into my gem and load them into rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, helper

Im working into a gem to make some tests, i'v already loaded methods from lib and used them into my app, the problem here is i am trying to call the:

**app/helpers/test_helper.rb**

```
module TestHelper
  def tags_inserted(person)
    content_tag(:p, "Hello #{person}!")
  end
end
```

and when i write:

```
= tags_inserted('myname')
```

inside my code it just says:

```
undefined method `tags_inserted' for #<#<Class:0x00000003efdc80>:0x00000003fce4c0>
```

i'v made some search and everyone says the standard for helpers in gems is to put them inside **/lib** directorie, but my boss tells me placing them in **/app/helpers/** should work, what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I did it with rails 2.
I've placed helper module in lib directory with following line added in init.rb which is placed in root directory of a gem/plugin:

```
ActionController::Base.helper TestHelper
```

It makes TestHelper module methods available for template. Here is how above helper method works: [helper method](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper)

Comment: I made it to call the method, changed some stuff but called it as = Newgem.tags_inserted, i t says: undefined method content_tag(), its amazing because it is suposed to be part of ruby isnt it?

Comment: It's part of rails but probaby rails is not a part of your gem, so this method is not available for You. You have to add action view as a dependency in a newgem.gemspec. Then include a module ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper. Require action_view will be probably needed too.